# Creating uppercase MySQL table names with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

I'm trying to create a table with the name `ID1` using this function:

```
public function createIDTable($IdNumber)
{
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE `Database`.`ID$IdNumber` (`Names` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL)";

        $query = mysql_query($sql)or die (mysql_error());
        return "Sucess";
}
```

It creates the table, but the names are always lowercase, like `id1`. I need `ID1` - how can I do it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't it be lowercase?

Comment: Just for convenience,another part of the system,already created uses that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed SQL Server with the default collation options, you might find that the following queries return the same results:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
( 
    mycolumn VARCHAR(10) 
) 
GO 

SET NOCOUNT ON 

INSERT mytable VALUES('Case') 
GO 

SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn='Case' 
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn='caSE' 
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn='case'
```

You can alter your query by forcing collation at the column level:

```
SELECT myColumn FROM myTable  
    WHERE myColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'caSE' 

SELECT myColumn FROM myTable  
    WHERE myColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'case' 

SELECT myColumn FROM myTable  
    WHERE myColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'Case' 

-- if myColumn has an index, you will likely benefit by adding 
-- AND myColumn = 'case'
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names

Be careful with this setting if you're running MySQL on a server with a case-insensitive file system (Windows).